# Puppeteer автоматизация с настроенной вкладкой

Tags: javascript, node.js, автоматизация, puppeteer

У меня есть открытая вкладка в браузере,ниже приведу код,как мне сделать так,чтобы автоматизация проходила по уже открытой вкладке,а не так,чтобы он открывал chronium.И можно ли увеличить скорость автоматизации?

```
    const Puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    const login = 'log';
    const password = 'pas';

    const sleep = (x) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,x));

    (async () => {
        const Browser = await Puppeteer.launch({
    headless:false
});
const page = await Browser.newPage();
await page.setViewport({
    width:1100,
    height:800
});
await page.goto("https://web.skype.com/");

const isElementPresented = async (selector) => {
    return await page.$(selector) !== null;
}

const inputEmailSelector = 'input[placeholder="Электронная почта, телефон или Skype"]';
const nextBtnSelector = 'input[value="Далее"]';
const inputPasswordSelector = 'input[placeholder="Пароль"]';
const signInButtonSelector = 'input[value="Вход"]';
const doNotAskCheckboxSelector = 'input[name="DontShowAgain"]';
const yesButtonSelector = 'input[aria-describedby="KmsiDescription"]';

if(await isElementPresented(inputEmailSelector)){
    await page.type(inputEmailSelector,login)
    await page.click(nextBtnSelector);
}
await sleep(1000);

if(await isElementPresented(inputPasswordSelector)){
    await page.type(inputPasswordSelector,password);
    await sleep(1000);
    await page.click(signInButtonSelector);
}
await sleep(1000);
if(await isElementPresented(doNotAskCheckboxSelector)){
    await page.click(doNotAskCheckboxSelector);
    await page.click(yesButtonSelector);
}

await new Promise(r => {});
await Browser.close();
```

})();

Comment: у тебя много раз повторяется этот скрипт или что??

Comment: В каком плане?)